# Typescript convention for types in variable defintions

Tags: typescript

In Typescript you can define a boolean variable in several ways e.g.:

```
let a = true;

let b: boolean = true;
```

Since `true` already is a boolean, is it still common to define it as variable type (as shown for b)?

If so, goes the same for all primitive types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript implicitly types variables based on the initial assignment ([Read more](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/type-inference.html)). So the two variables here are both typed as `boolean`:

```
let a = true;          // implicitly typed as boolean
let b: boolean = true; // explicitly typed as boolean
```

Both will error when assigning a different type:

```
a = "a string";        // error, type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
b = "a string";        // error, type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
```

There's no convention for whether you should be explicit or implicit, but I would highly recommend to drop the verbosity of `let a: boolean = true;`. It's shorter to write `let a = true;` instead. The assignment clearly shows the type already so there's really no need to be explicit and state that twice.

**Implicit Anys**

You should watch out for "implicit any types". This occurs when there is no assignment in the initial statement and no type specified:

```
let a; // implicitly typed as `any`
```

This variable can be used in any way:

```
a = true;       // ok
a = "a string"; // ok
```

In this case, you should be explicit about the type:

```
let a: boolean;
a = true;       // ok
a = "a string"; // error, type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean' -- good!
```

You can completely avoid accidentally defining implicit any types by turning on the compiler option [`--noImplicitAny`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), which will raise a compile error when you do so. I recommend to enable this.

```
let a; // compile error with `--noImplicitAny`
```

Comment: Do you have a source which shows TypeScript indeed implicitly types variables based on the initial assignment? Since I couldn't find one :)

Comment: @osi also, you can test out the code. You will see what's said in the current selected answer is wrong because it doesn't take type inference into account.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew about `type inference`, the documentation made it very clear

Comment: When you define a `void` function is it also best practice to leave the `void` return type out of the function definition?

Comment: @osi the best practice is debatable. Usually I keep my functions small enough that I can understand the type from the return statement. If there's no return statement then I know it's `void`. Related: Enabling the `noImplicitReturns` compiler option is good.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, with the first approach, you don't define a type (for TypeScript) so you can potential put what you want in the `a` variable as value. Don't forget that JavaScript is dynamic. Moreover you can't check at compilation that the correct type is provided when using the variable.

You could have this:

```
let a = true;
a = 'test';
```

With the second approach, you can check at compilation time that the type of the `b` is exactly what is expected: when used as parameter of a method, when affected to another property of variable, ...

It's better to leverage the strong typing of TypeScript for static checking. This will allow you to easily detect potential problems during the implementation phase (and not at runtime).

For example:

```
let a:boolean = true;
a = 'test'; // compilation error
```